# Problems with CSS rendering on IE9; Conditional statements not a fix

Tags: internet-explorer, css, internet-explorer-9

Hey guys, for the most part, IE9 renders my Wordpress based website just fine. By just fine I mean acceptable for now. The only problem is IE9 doesn't show the background or text for my homepage widget titles. For browsers like Firefox, Chrome, Safari etc. etc. I am using a red gradient background with white text and rounded corners which of course work fine. For IE9 I added a conditional statement to set the background of the widget title as a solid red color with no rounded corners. Unfortunately this did not solve the problem. The background still does not show up. The crazy thing is, when I open up the website in IE7 using Wine on my Mac, the widget title background shows up with the solid color...

As a second measure of testing I set the background as a solid color with no rounded corners on the main stylesheet to see if it would work that in IE9. Of course, it did not. Even with the main css file changed the background/text of the widget title still did not show up. I am really out of ideas as to what could be wrong and I was wondering if I could get some help.

You can find the website by going to bso.larryandpriscilla.com

Ok, for the widget title here is the code. Is there any other code that would be helpful?

```
.widget-title {
    color: #fff;
    width:300px;
    margin-left: -1px;
    height:30px;
    margin-top: -30px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.5) 1px 1px 1px; 
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px; 
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px; 
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px; 
    background: #A50000; /* old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #A50000 0%, #670000 100%); /* firefox */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#A50000), color-stop(100%,#670000)); /* webkit */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#A50000', endColorstr='#670000',GradientType=0 );
}
```

Here is the conditional statement I used. I am not sure if matters but I put it in the header section of the header file:

```
<!--[if gt IE 6]>
<style type="text/css">
     .widget-title {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #A50000;
        width:300px;
        margin-left: -1px;
        height:30px;
        margin-top: -30px;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-weight: 400;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Here is the current conditional comment:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<style type="text/css">
     .widget-title {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #A50000;
        width:300px;
    margin-top: 0px;
        margin-left: -1px;
        height:30px
        text-align: center;
        font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-weight: 400;
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#A50000', endColorstr='#670000',GradientType=0 );
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: No support for IE8, and a "please upgrade" message? That's a tall order. It'll probably take ten years until we've seen the last of IE8 :)

Comment: whats your conditional statement?

Comment: Can you show some of the code in question here? E.g. the CSS you're using to define the background.

Comment: have you tried using the if IE conditional just to check if IE9 gets the styles?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that but still go luck. Because it's a Wordpress site does it matter where the conditional tag is placed?

Answer (score 1):

In IE8 (thanks for making me work to hide the browser upgrade message!), the widget titles are there but the `margin-top:-30px` is shifting them below the widget content. I would have a look at the layout in general as I took the `margin-top` out and some scroll bars appeared. In particular you have `<li>` elements not inside a `<ul>` or `<ol>`. Browsers will have to do a best guess for the missing elements when rendering the page. I would start by making the [page validate](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://bso.larryandpriscilla.com&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0). Another idea could be to mark-up the 3 widgets differently, for example this could be a basis for a similar layout without float or negative margins:

```
<style type="text/css">
    ul { list-style-type:none; }
    li { display:inline-block; }
</style>
<ul>
    <li>
        <h4>Title</h4>
        <div>Content</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h4>Title</h4>
        <div>Content</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h4>Title</h4>
        <div>Content</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

as [inline-block](http://caniuse.com/#search=inline-block) is well supported for your target browsers.

Hope this is useful.

**Edit:** Looking at your conditional comment in more detail… you should not need to repeat the properties if they are the same as in the `style.css`. Although **[this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/836Hr/3/)** does not re-create the problem exactly you should be able to see the difference the conditional comment makes, i.e. the big padding that only appears in IE6+.

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much for the help. Although that fixed the problem, it only fixes it if I take out the margin-top command from the main css file. It I add a conditional statement it doesn't work. Is there a specific place the conditional statement needs to go?

Comment: The conditional comment looks fine to me. It can theoretically go anywhere in the document since it is just a regular HTML comment that IE has been programmed to recognise. In IE8 it looks like the `margin-top` is being applied as part of the `filter` though. Could you try moving the filter to the conditional comment style block and also change the `margin-top` in that conditional comment.

Comment: Ok, here is what I have for the conditional comment:     `code`               <!--[if IE]>
<style type="text/css">
     .widget-title {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #A50000;
        width:300px;
 margin-top: 0px;
        margin-left: -1px;
        height:30px
        text-align: center;
        font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-weight: 400;
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#A50000', endColorstr='#670000',GradientType=0 );
}
</style>
<![endif]-->

Comment: That should be fine as long as the filter does not still exist in your main `style.css`.

Comment: Added a quick demo to my answer to demonstrate how the conditional comment should be working.